# Can I submit a form with a ckEditor textarea using php?

Tags: php

I have a form with a text field for a title and a textarea, courtesy of ckEditor, for the message. Only the title is posted. What do I need to do to post the textarea value?

Comment: print_r($_POST); if that does not show you the right name to use, post the form code.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your closing form tag is **after** the textarea.

Double check your **textarea name attribute**.

In case you are still in doubt, in the page mentioned in your form action attribute, paste the following code:

```
<pre>
POST DATA:
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
GET DATA:
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
</pre>
```

You should see your textarea data.

If not, please send your code for a more accurate answer...

Comment: <form action="updateComments.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
 Title <br />
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $commenttitle?>"/><br />
Comment <br />
<?php
 $CKEditor = new CKEditor();
 $CKEditor->editor("editor1", "$usercomment"); 
?>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"><?php echo $usercomment?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add to List in editted form">
</form>

POST DATA:
Array
(
    [title] => q
    [editor1] => 
)
GET DATA:
Array
(
)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to add that I tried your code to see the post and as you can see it is empty.

Comment: I have tried some other code to getElementbyID and pass it to a function and that does post something but it comes out gibberish on the other side

Comment: Making progress. The getElementbyID function captures the textarea value but it also includes tags(eg <p>Text</p>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function replaceChars(entry) {
   temp = "" + entry; // temporary holder
   document.getElementById('editor1').value = temp;
}

</script>
 
 <form method="POST" action="addComments.php" onsubmit="replaceChars(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData())" >